# Wordpress options tabs how to change active class

Tags: php, wordpress

This is my first time building a tabbed options page. I found the following code in a tutorial (I only included the relevant code here):

```
function mytheme_admin_tabs( $current = 'general' ) { 
    $tabs = array( 'general' => 'General', 'social' => 'Social Media', 'bottom' => 'Page Bottom', 'footer' => 'Footer' ); 
    $links = array(); 
    foreach( $tabs as $tab => $name ) : 
        if ( $tab == $current ) : 
            $links[] = "<a class='nav-tab nav-tab-active' href='?page=theme_options&tab=$tab'>$name</a>"; 
        else : 
            $links[] = "<a class='nav-tab' href='?page=theme_options&tab=$tab'>$name</a>"; 
        endif; 
    endforeach; 
    echo '<div class="option-tabs">'; 
    foreach ( $links as $link ) 
        echo $link; 
    echo '<div class="clear"></div></div>'; 
}
```

Everything is functioning as it should, however when I click on a different tab, the class 'nav-tab-active' does not get removed from the original or added to the newly active tab. The tutorial didn't mention anything about this. What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: please describe the problem your attempting to solve so the community can find you a solution, rather than asking for a bugfix on your code (without reference to tutorial you copied from)

Comment: I would recommend not using a script for this but making it yourself. It's way easier! Just use `if(isset($_GET['tab']) && $_GET['tab'] == 'your-tab') {`.